# Get a node variable

Tags: neo4j

I've created some nodes and I'm attempting to create relationships among them. But I forgot the node variable (**variable:**label). Is there a way to get it or to match a node without it?

Comment: is simple, the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "variable" - or more precisely the identifier is nowhere persisted. It's scope is just the current statement and used to have a reference back to that node, e.g. to return one of its properties.

To find your node you need to know its label and (maybe) a property value:

```
MATCH (n:<mylabel>) WHERE n.<key>=<value> RETURN n
```

Omitting the `WHERE` clause will give you all the nodes carrying that label.

Comment: this non-univoque characteristic of the identifier applies also to properties identifiers? can I match a node declaring it's property value without its name? like: `match (n:label{n:'red'})` ?

Comment: then you'd set the property `n=red` on a node with local identifer `n` and label `label`.

Comment: If you want to match a node of a given label and the precise value of a unknown property: `MATCH (n:MyLabel) WHERE any(x in keys(n) WHERE n[x]='myvalue') RETURN n`